# Pylucene 4.9.0 Ubuntu 14.04 Installation ImportError

Tags: python, ubuntu, lucene, pylucene

I've been trying to install Pylucene on my Mac for a little over a week, and have given up on that in favor of trying to install it with Ubuntu through a virtual machine. I thought the installation process had gone well, so I fired up Python in the terminal and tried to `import lucene` and received the following `ImportError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/parallels/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lucene/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import _lucene
ImportError: libverify.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So, it looks like there is a module `_lucene` that does not exist. But I thought this would have been part of what I had just installed? Any insight here would be appreciated.

Comment: PuLucene package require some additional soft. Please check if you meet all requirements 
http://bendemott.blogspot.com/2013/11/installing-pylucene-4-451.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to add extra paths to my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to get things working.  The test [here](https://github.com/kalefranz/conda-packages/blob/master/pylucene/meta.yaml#L28:L31) in the conda build script actually shows those variables.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PREFIX/lib:$PREFIX/jre/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PREFIX/jre/lib/amd64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PREFIX/jre/lib/amd64/server:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PREFIX/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

`$PREFIX` here is the path to the anaconda folder.  I currently install miniconda at `/usr/conda` on my systems.